# How do I name and control individual children in an iOS game?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift programming and I'm working with the default code that's created when you create a new game app.  Currently when you run the app, every time you click the screen it creates a new spinning spaceship.

I want to know how to name each "child" and then control them individually after.  So basically if I name them bob1, bob2, bob3...  How can I move or resize bob2?

Once they're created, I don't know how to access them or modify them.

Thanks in advance. :)

Below is my code so far...

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  OSX App
//
//  Created by Administrator on 2016-02-11.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Administrator. All rights reserved.
//
import SpriteKit
var x = 0

class GameScene: SKScene {
    //let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        myLabel.text = "My First App"
        myLabel.fontSize = 45
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        /* Called when a mouse click occurs */
        let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)


        sprite.position = location;
        sprite.setScale(0.5)

        //let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
        //sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        self.addChild(sprite)
        var xyPos : CGPoint

        //Increment name for each object
        x++
        sprite.name = "Bob" + "\(x)"
        print(sprite.name)
        xyPos = sprite.position
        print(xyPos)

    }
    override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    //When a key is pressed, move a child of "Sprite"
        //For example, if I press the "B" key, move "Bob1"

    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        //for child in self.children {
        //    print(child.position.x)
        //}



        //x++
        //print(x)
        //x++
        //print(x)
        ///if x == 1000 {
        //    print("Yay")
            //SKSpriteNode.
            //SKSpriteNode.childNodeWithName(sprite)
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: A `SKSpriteNode` inherits from `SKNode`, which has a `name` property.  Look at the `SKNode` documentation under the heading "Searching the Node Tree".

Comment: Do you mean naming your variables bob1, bob2 ? That's not possible in this way. What you need is a data structure that knows all your spaceships and then you need a strategy to identify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: you made `sprite` a property of `GameScene`.

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
```

Now you are no longer able to add multiple sprites to you scene, don't you?

### Next

As @PhilipMills noted in the comments, you can assign a `name` to a sprite (of to every other `SKNode` subclass).

So if you write

```
sprite.name = "enemy1"
self.addChild(sprite)
```

later on you can retrive it writing

```
let enemy = self.childNodeWithName("enemy1") as? SKSpriteNode
```